# OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient no funciona!

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cache

Estoy usando `OutPutCache` con el parámetro `OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient` en una acción que siempre me retorna imágenes; sin embargo, el navegador siempre descarga las imágenes (no las guarda en cache), si uso `OutputCacheLocation.Client` funciona perfectamente pero necesito que la cache sea del lado del servidor y el cliente.

No entiendo lo que sucede. Éste es mi código:

```
[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(Duration = 43200,Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult GetImagenProducto(int id, int width = 800, int height = 800, int calidad = 90)
{
```

Comment: Hola @Davis, por favor completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y sobre su funcionamiento general. Stack Overflow no es un foro donde publicas un post y editas tu pregunta para poner la solución. SO es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde en una sección tienes la pregunta y en otra tienes las respuestas. Es genial que hayas encontrado la solución y que la hayas compartido, pero deberías hacerlo en la sección de respuestas (puedes responder a tu propia pregunta sin problemas). Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información.

Comment: Cuando publiques la respuesta, recuerda añadir una explicación de qué hace o cómo funciona y no sólo poner el enlace.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución en el sitio en inglés. Ésta es una traducción de la [respuesta de AlexC:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052398/3695983)

Puedes usar `OutputCacheLocation.Any`que especifica que

> La caché de salida puede encontrarse en el navegador del cliente (donde la petición se originó), en el servidor proxy (o cualquier otro servidor) participando en la petición, o en el servidor donde la petición fue procesada. Este valor corresponde al valor de enumeración `HttpCacheability.Public`.

Puede que quieras también especificar Cache-control a public en la cabecera HTTP para esas peticiones.

Edición

Parece que dependiendo de la versión de .Net del servidor, puede que necesites incluir `Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);` en la acción del controlador para quitar el Vary * headers como sugieres.

Detalles de la razón por qué en las [notas de publicación de .Net 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770157).